# How to "soft append" directories to $PATH?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Suppose `echo $PATH` produces `/first/path:/second/path:/third/path`, but you -- as a script writer -- don't know this. That said, your goal is to append the contents of `$PATH` with `$PATH1`. Now `$PATH1` may or may not have overlap with `$PATH` (for example: both `$PATH` and `$PATH1` might share `/second/path` in common).

**Question:** How does one accomplish the effect of `PATH=$PATH:$PATH1`, but avoiding the duplication problem discussed above?

Answer (score 2):

This will add `path1` to the end of `PATH` but only if it is not a duplicate:

```
case ":${PATH:=$path1}:" in
    *:$path1:*)  ;;
    *) PATH="$PATH:$path1"  ;;
esac
```

This is POSIX and therefore portable.

Note that I used lower case for the `path1` variable.  The system variables are all upper case.  To avoid accidentally overwriting one, it is good practice to use lower or mixed case for one's personal variables.